# Converting a list of JSON objects into one JSON object in R

Tags: r, json, jsonlite

I'm working on a project for school that requires me to combine ~600 JSON files into one CSV file. I have minimal coding knowledge in R, and I keep getting errors that I can't resolve, probably due to my minimal knowledge. Here's the code I'm using:

```
filenames <- list.files(pattern="*.json")

myJson <- lapply(filenames, function(x) fromJSON(file=x))
```

This returns a list of the JSON contents of all my files (hooray), and it's where things break down. If I use:

```
myJson <- toJSON(myJson)
```

to try converting all my list of JSON data into one JSON, I get this error:

```
Error in toJSON(myJson) : unable to escape string. String is not utf8
```

If I use `unlist(myJson)`, I lose all the columns and get a useless single column of all my data. Any assistance would be hugely appreciated! Thank you.